# Resilience4j + Grafana dashboard, works with Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker?

Tags: java, grafana, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Question about the Grafana dashboard found here: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/grafana-1

This dashboard is very interesting! However, we are currently using the Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker Resilience4j, not Resilience4j directly.

I was wondering if this Grafana Dashboard still applies please?

The reason I am asking, and not just to try it, is because we do not have an instance of Grafana. Hence the question.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no.
You can use `resilience4j-micrometer`, but if you don't use the starter project `resilience4j-spring-boot2`, you have to configure it manually.